# How to pass predefined function to async

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I am a bit confused how to pass a predefined function inside async.

The following code works perfectly

```
async.auto({
    getAccessToken: function (callback) {
        let x = {
            access_token: signToken({ userId: user._id }),
            client: req.user._id,
            user: user._id,
            scope: user.scopes,
            expires: new Date().setDate(new Date().getMinutes() + 15)
        };

        callback(null, x);
    }
}, (err, res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

But i want to use a predefined function inside the async auto tasklist.

for example:
and for that i need to pass some values to it. i am stuck here.

```
async.auto({
    getAccessToken: generateAccessToken // this is where i am stuck
}, (err, res) => {
    Logger.info('here');
    Logger.info(res);
});

generateAccessToken = (user, client, cb) => {
    // cb(null, 'asd')
    let accessToken = new AccessToken({
        access_token: signToken({ userId: user._id }),
        client: client,
        user: user._id,
        scope: user.scopes,
        expires: new Date().setDate(new Date().getMinutes() + 15)
    });

    accessToken.save((err, token) => {
        if (err) {
            cb(err, null);
            return;
        }
        cb(null, token);
        return;
    });
}
```

if i pass values i get the following errors:

```
return supportsSymbol && fn[Symbol.toStringTag] === 'AsyncFunction';
                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem with the following solution.

```
async.auto({
                    getAccessToken: ((cb) => {
                        generateAccessToken(user, req.user._id, cb)
                    })
                }, (err, res) => {
                    Logger.info('here');
                    Logger.info(res);
                });
```

Not sure if its the best solution or not. so will keep the question open for some time. thanks